# Connect event of redis client called mutiple times when using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

I am using node + redis and I facing strange issue when ever I run my app ,  connect event of redis client is called multiple times automatically as  written in redis.js file.

Below is my code Server.js:

```
        var express=require('express');
        var app=express();
        var port=8000;
        var path = require('path');
        var logger=require('morgan');
        var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
        var router = express.Router();

        app.use(logger('dev'));

        app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
        app.use(bodyParser.json());

        app.get('/',function(req,res){
            res.send({message:"Welcome to nodejs APIS"});
        });

        var redisObj=require('./redis.js');
        app.use('/redischeck',redisObj);

        app.listen(port,function(err,res){ if(err){ console.log("Server error");}else{console.log("Server running on port 8000");}});
```

redis.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var redis = require("redis");
var client = redis.createClient();

 client.on('connect', function() {
console.log('connected'); // Prints multiple time in console
});

router.get('/', function(req, res) {

client.on("error", function (err) { console.log("Error " + err);});

client.set("foo", "bar", function (err, reply) {

  client.quit();

  res.json({status:'Success'});
 });
 });

module.exports=router;
```

I also cross checked this issue using 'netstat -na | grep 6379'.My observation were many connection were created and then went in to TIME_WAIT state which was strange because I just ran my app on my localhost without anyone connecting it from some other end.

Am I doing something wrong in code.

Comment: Connect will be called multiple times because you're closing the connection after every request to your root path. If you remove `client.quit` and move it to when the server shuts down you should only see 1 connection.

Comment: I commented that line but still same.Also I am the only user accessing the node app and connection starts creating itself once I run the app without navigating through URL's

Comment: Does it keep creating connections even with no activity? You might need to post some more code to debug that.

Comment: Yes it keeps creating connection without no activity at all once I run the app using 'node server.js'.There are only two files in my code which i have copied above.

Comment: I just ran your code and it only creates a single connection. The only thing I noticed is that your `client.on('error', ...)` should be declared outside of your route. How are you running your server? Can you provide the output in your console?

Comment: @mrwillihog your are right when I ran same code in different machine it worked fine.May be I messed up some values in redis.conf file

Answer (score 0):

It was a mistake from my side I had changed timeout values in redis.conf file located at /etc/redis/redis.conf so that redis connection does not go in TIME_WAIT state for 60 sec.